# how to take value outside jbutton actionlistener?

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtextfield

how to access value from outside the actionlistener

```
jbtnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    private String ana_data;

    @SuppressWarnings("override")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {
        ana_data=jtf.getText();  
    }
});          

pos_pred=def_pred(f_path,ana_data,prob_p,poslen,pcount);
neg_pred=def_pred(f_path1,ana_data,prob_n,neglen,ncount);
```

I need to take the data from outside the ActionListener inside the method given after that? can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that.

The reason is that the `ActionListener` is executed later in time when the rest of the method is already run.

So if you want to work with something that depends on the action listener you have to move it there (or in a method tat is called from the `ActionListener` .

Answer (score 0):

One of possible general patterns to tackle problems where some part of your code depends on values from code executed asynchronously is to use promises (`CompletableFuture` in Java). Generally it is advisable to design your overall code asynchronously in such situations, so that the method producing the value and the method requiring the value can both proceed at some even at some later point in time. From you question it is not clear if you can design it that way in your case. So I will assume you cannot. If your caller cannot behave asynchronously and needs the result of an asynchronous operation within a synchronous flow, then you will need to block the thread waiting for the result:

```
CompletableFuture<String> anaDataPromise = new CompletableFuture<>();
jbtnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("override")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {
        anaDataPromise.complete(jtf.getText());
    }
});
anaData = anaDataPromise.get(); // will block until action performed
// anaData = anaDataPromise.get(10, TimeUnit.MINUTE); // will block until action performed or for max of 10 minutes
```

If you could permit the code that needs the `anaData` value to be fully asynchronous, then you could write it in a non-blocking fashion:

```
CompletableFuture<String> anaDataPromise = new CompletableFuture<>();
jbtnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("override")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {
        anaDataPromise.complete(jtf.getText());
    }
});
anaDataPromise.whenComplete((anaData, throwable) -> {
    if (throwable != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
    }
    // do something with anaData value
});
// this point is reached immediately as the above code simply declares 
// the action that will run later, the actions themselves are not yet run
```